# How to process more than 10K records from batch in one Transaction?

Tags: batch, dmlexception

we have a functionality as following:
on VF page we define some criteria say e.g
Account Name = Nachiket and some other configurations.

configuration details we store in custom object say Custom Object 1 & we store 
criteria details "Account Name = Nachiket" custom object 2 which is child of Custom Object 1.

We have Batch Apex written over Custom Object1.

> ```
> public with sharing class myBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
>   public void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
>     {
>         //Query Locator Fetches data from Custom Object 1.
>       //Inside Execute we evaluate criteria 
>       //we prepare Query String 
>       //so for criteria AccountName = Nachiket.
>       //We execute query as follow.
>       //Select Id,Name from Account Where Name=:"Nachiket"
>       //This will give us "N" Number of Accounts which qualifies criteria.
>
>       //Now we do iterations on these records and create new records of custom object.
>
>       Problem we are facing here , as in one transaction we can have 10K DML rows ,
>       we are getting issue of "Too Many DML Rows" , when clients org has records
>       qualified more than 10k.
>     }
> }
> ```

How to overcome this scnario if from execute I have to process more than 10K records by seperating out transaction.
Any help will be appricated.

Answer (score 4):

Your batch is written against the wrong object.

Since a single record of ProgramObject actually *defines* the batch operation, while the batch operation itself takes place on Account, you should pull your ProgramObject details in your batch class's `start()` method, and use them to create a `QueryLocator` that `start()` will return, such as your example

```
Select Id,Name from Account Where Name='Nachiket'
```

Then, your `execute()` method should operate on the `scope` of 200 (or your batch size) Accounts that are passed to it, generate the custom objects that are needed, and insert them. Because each trip through `execute()` operates only on a single scope's worth of records, you should stay comfortably below your 10,000 row DML limit. You may in fact be able to raise your batch size above 200 for greater speed while still remaining within limits.

The way you've structured the batch right now loses you all the benefits of Batch Apex, including resilience against limits, because you've placed all of the volume in a single batch iteration. Each run through `execute()` should generally execute queries only against the scope of records that are passed to it or their related records (if you can guarantee the related records have compatible data volume).

Any time you find yourself writing a broad-based query in `execute()`, you're likely to be in a situation where you're misusing Batch Apex.

### Broader Context

As we discussed in comments, you've built a kind of generalized engine that does data updates and/or record creation based on dynamic, user-defined criteria, where there might be as many as 50 ProgramObject records across multiple sObjects.

This is a pretty complex code-architecture issue, and I don't think I can *solve* it here, but I'll sketch some ideas that I would personally pursue.

My first thought is that this might be a great application for Batch Chaining. Assuming that the number of sObjects involved is a small integer, what I would look to do is build a "dispatcher" class that sorted your ProgramObject  records by sObject. Then, for each sObject, it would spawn one batch class, providing it with a list of the ProgramObjects for a single sObject. (At this level, the child object of ProgramObject isn't very important to the architecture - you can pull those in either at the start of the dispatch process or in each batch's `start()` method).

Each batch class would run the first update defined by the first ProgramObject  in its list, then, in its `finish()` method, chain into a new batch class, passing along its ProgramObject list minus the first item - the one it just executed.

When the list is emptied, the batches would stop chaining themselves.

In this fashion, you could achieve several important points:

- Serializing the updates to each sObject, which would also allow you to define which order they run in.
- Staying within row limits throughout.
- Keeping the number of running/enqueued batches relatively low.
- Preventing batches on the same object from interfering with one another through lock contention, because they run serially.

Comment: I can't do that since my use case is different , there will be multiple records of custom object 1 which will have different set of criterias defined so I can't write batch apex on child object.

Comment: Why not? How many records of Custom Object 1 do you expect to have?

Comment: May be around 50 or so !

Comment: Oof. Are they on different sObjects? But more than one per sObject?

Comment: Yes , user can define criteria on multiple Sobjects , so in backend we store it in List<Sobject> and then map values to create new object records,( if I correctly understood your question)

Comment: Yeah, I think I follow you. I'll add a suggestion about the overall architecture but that's going to be pretty complex to handle limits-wise.

Comment: my objec structure is like
ProgramObject --> and its related object which holds the criteria (AccountName=Nachiket) here user can enter multiple criterias

Comment: Got it, I will edit to use ProgramObject where I mean that above